# Delete a row if it doesn't contain a specified integer value (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataset that I want to clean up prior to applying my ML algorithm. I am wondering if it was possible to remove a row if an element of its columns does not match a set of values. For example, if I have the dataframe:

```
    a    b    
0   1    6    
1   4    7    
2   2    4    
3   3    7    
...
```

And I desire the values of `a` to be one of `[1,3]` and of `b` to be one of `[6,7]`, such that my final dataset is:

```
    a    b
0   1    6
1   3    7
...
```

Currently, my implementation is not working as some of my data rows have erroneous strings attached to the value. For example, instead of a value of `1` I'll have something like `1abc`. Hence why I would like to remove anything that is not an integer of that value.

My workaround is also a bit archaic, as I am removing entries for column `a` that do not have 1 or 3 via:

```
dataset = dataset[(dataset.commute != 1)]
dataset = dataset[(dataset.commute != 3)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with double [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) and `&`:

```
df1 = df[(df['a'].isin([1,3])) & (df['b'].isin([6,7]))]
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  6
3  3  7
```

Or use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
df1 = df[(np.in1d(df['a'], [1,3])) & (np.in1d(df['b'], [6,7])) ]
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  6
3  3  7
```

But if need remove all rows with non numeric then need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` which return `NaN` and then is possible filter it by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1abc','2','3'],
                   'b':['4','5','dsws7']})

print (df)
      a      b
0  1abc      4
1     2      5
2     3  dsws7

mask = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce').notnull() & 
       pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df1 = df[mask].astype(int)
print (df1)
   a  b
1  2  5
```

If need check if some value is `NaN` or `None`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1abc',None,'3'],
                   'b':['4','5',np.nan]})
print (df)
      a    b
0  1abc    4
1  None    5
2     3  NaN

print (df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)])
      a    b
1  None    5
2     3  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Works like a charm :) I was getting a type issue when using `astype()` on an object dataset before your explanation.

Comment: Glad can help. Good luck!

Comment: I am however getting one last error despite understanding what's going on. Running `df = df[mask].astype(int)` leads me to the error `ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer`. Observing the column shows that is now a Boolean type where all values containing a string are `False`, otherwise are `True`. Seems to make sense logically so far.

Comment: It means in your data are some `NaN` values. So need replace them e.g. to `0` by `df[mask].fillna(0).astype(int)` .

Comment: Observing the data, there are no `NaN` values - only `True` or `False`. I will investigate further. EDIT: Fixed! Works now!

Comment: It is weird, because `pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce').notnull() & 
       pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce').notnull()` has to filter `NaN`s :(. If dont find problem and data are not confidental, you can send it to my email in my profile and I can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas isin()

```
df = df[df.a.isin([1,3]) & df.b.isin([6,7])]

    a   b
0   1   6
3   3   7
```